# Why does macOS show ".local" domain name for TimeMachine server when my network is configured for ".lan"

Tags: macos, network, time-machine

I have a TrueNAS server running on my network that provides TimeMachine services.  My network DHCP server is configured to provide `.lan` as the domain name.

However, when I go to Time Machine preferences, I see the server as `zfs.local` instead of `zfs.lan`.

Why does that happen?

I have another machine that sees the same servers as `zfs.lan` properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be occurring due to accidental usage of Avahi/Bonjour. If you mount the Time Machine volume to your Mac and click 'Get Info' on a file stored on it, you may see something like `smb://lunar._smb._tcp.local/Chrono/`. This indicates that the server was automatically discovered because it offered an SMB service. If you were connecting via the hostname it would read `smb://lunar.local`. If this seems accurate, the solution is to either disable Avahi or Bonjour on your server, or to manually mount via the hostname and change your Time Machine disk.

Comment: Disabling mDNS (Avahi/Bonjour) seems more likely to cause trouble than to solve it. I'd try the manual mount approach first.

Comment: The "manual mount before selecting Time Machine drive" solution worked the best!  Thanks for that tip.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and would like to add that configuring TrueNAS' domain to a different one (`.lan` in my case as well) did not change how it seemed to respond to mDNS. I think that might not be possible to configure, and, depending on how you look at it, that apparently might be a good thing overall. It's unfortunate, since `.local` does not reliably resolve, and manually mounting will make both the mDNS host (in my case, `truenas`) and the manually mounted host (`truenas.lan`) both show up in Finder's sidebar... but hopefully it fixes the resolution issues permanently!